# Select Page object class on runtime based on driver type

Tags: java, selenium, automation, frameworks, appium

So i am building a page object model framework for a mobile native app.
 I have separate classes for IOS and android page objects. I have used singelton design pattern to instantiate the driver based on OS type. Now i want my test case to reference the page object class on run time based on the OS type.How can i achieve this. As of now i have a testcase class TestHomepage,a page object class, a driver class which is initialising  driver based on OS type, a utility method to get OS type from onfig property file and a property file where i am storing OS type.Code i use in the page object class Homepage to initialize driver is

```
public Homepage() {
    driver = (AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>) TestBase.Instance;
}

// utility method and singleton design
public static String os(){
    try {
        String OS=getobject("Os");
        return OS;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;        
}


public static String OS=os();
public static WebDriver Instance=null;
public static void Initialize() throws IOException{
    if (Instance==null){
        if(OS.equalsIgnoreCase("Android"))
            Instance=capabilities();

        else if (OS.equalsIgnoreCase("IOS")){
            Instance=ioscap();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when is needed for

> my test case to reference the page object class on run time based on the OS type

I use [Strategy](http://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern) design pattern, because it allows me to

> Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

Based on `public static String OS=os();` value you can reference the needed IOS or Android page objects and their action methods.

One more option, which might work and is way simpler - [Dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). Note, that some people don't like this design choice, because it might be leading to reliance upon the technique. Also it violates the Open/Closed Principle, and in case you plan to support numerous platforms, would be in a particularly egregious way.

Comment: Thank you, can you please give an example of strategy pattern implementation?

Comment: The very first link I've posted in my answer is JAVA implementation with function composition leveraging :)